# Python 3 IndexError: list index out of range, working from CSV type file

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I get the "IndexError: list index out of range" when trying this code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

nameFile = input('Enter raw data txt filename to plot >>>')

print('plotting file {}:'.format(nameFile))

with open(nameFile, 'r') as readFile:

    sepFile = readFile.read().split('\n')

    x = []

    y = []


    for line in sepFile:

        cols = line.split(' ')
        X = float(cols[2])
        Y = float(cols[3])
        x.append(X)
        y.append(Y)

plt.plot(X, Y)
plt.show()
```

Im pulling from a CSV type file that is formatted as such:

```
1   6887.79 245441
2   6883.52 234833
3   6879.26 231316
4   6874.99 243267
5   6870.72 254817
6   6866.46 267046
7   6862.19 277514
8   6857.92 282874
9   6853.65 283163
10  6849.39 285764    ....etc etc
```

I have used similar code on files like this so as to why its not working is probably so simple I am gonna laugh at myself.

Answer (score 0):

[Python uses 0-based indexing](https://plus.google.com/115212051037621986145/posts/YTUxbXYZyfi). So `cols[0]` is the first value in `cols`, `cols[1]` is the second value, and so on.

So:

```
for line in sepFile:
    cols = line.split(' ')
    X = float(cols[1])      # <-- change 2 to 1
    Y = float(cols[2])      # <-- change 3 to 2
    x.append(X)
    y.append(Y)

plt.plot(x, y)              # <-- change X to x, Y to y
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

The list starts at 0, not at 1.

Try:

```
X = float(cols[1])
Y = float(cols[2])
```